# Party for its own identity facing error : Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants

Tags: corda

After Corda enterprise upgrade from 4.5 to 4.6, following existing flow is failing with the error for its own identity

```
    val customState = CustomState(ourIdentity)

        val txBuilder = with(TransactionBuilder(notary)) {
            addOutputState(customState)
            addCommand(Command(), ourIdentity.owningKey)
        }

        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)

        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx, emptyList()))
```

we are executing above flow on PARTYA node. CustomState have only one participant which is PARTYA. we are getting below error on FinalityFlow call

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Flow sessions were not provided for the following transaction participants: [CN=PARTYA, O=PARTYA, L=London, C=GB]
    at net.corda.node.internal.aliasing.flows.EnterpriseFinalityFlow.call(EnterpriseFinalityFlow.kt:70) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.aliasing.flows.EnterpriseFinalityFlow.call(EnterpriseFinalityFlow.kt:30) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.subFlow(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:429) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:414) ~[corda-core-4.6.jar:?]
    at com.custom.CustomFlow.call(CustomFlow.kt:27) ~[?:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:356) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:76) ~[corda-node-4.6.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1105) ~[quasar-core-0.7.13_r3.jar:0.7.13_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:801) ~[quasar-core-0.7.13_r3.jar:0.7.13_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:102) ~[quasar-core-0.7.13_r3.jar:0.7.13_r3]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:93) ~[quasar-core-0.7.13_r3.jar:0.7.13_r3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_272]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.46.Final.jar:4.1.46.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_272]
```

build.gradle deployNodes task PARTYA node details

```
node {
        name "CN=PARTYA,O=PARTYA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 50014
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:50015")
            adminAddress("localhost:50055")
        }
        cordapps = []
        extraConfig = ext.extraConfig + [
                'h2Settings'    : [address: "localhost:50042"]
        ]
        rpcUsers = [[user: "john", "password": "doe", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your flow isn't supplying flow sessions? That's what the exception you have there is saying.

You need to collect the flow sessions and supply them instead of maybe just signInitialTransaction.

```java
            List<FlowSession> sessions = otherParties
                    .stream().map(el -> initiateFlow(el))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            SignedTransaction stx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(ptx, sessions));
```

source: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/obligation/flows/IOUIssueFlow.java#L78-L82

If you're using corda enterprise you are free to contact support, I guarantee you they can help with this.